# «Крепкорассольный» как пишется?

Tags: орфография, лексика, словообразование, сложные-слова, сложные-прилагательные

Как пишется прилагательное «крепкорассольный»? Если оно обрзовано от словосочетания «крепкий рассол», значит, слитно?

Comment: Так и пишется, слитно.

Comment: О!Отлично!Спасибо!

Comment: Можно даже посмотреть в Интернете для убедительности: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/34781/крепкорассольный